# How to convert a variable argument function into a macro?

Tags: c, function, macros, variadic-functions

I have a variable argument function which prints error messages in my application, whose code is given below:

```
void error(char *format,...)
{   va_list args;
    printf("Error: ");
    va_start(args, format);
    vfprintf(stderr, format, args);
    va_end(args);
    printf("\n");
    abort(); 
}
```

This function is used in error conditions as follows:

```
error("invalid image width %d and image height %d in GIF file %s",wid,hei,name);
```

The `error()` function is called from different places with different arguments (variable argument function).

The function approach works fine.

Now, if I have to convert this function into a macro, how do I do it? I tried doing it as:

```
#define error(format)  {va_list args;\
    printf("Error: ");\
    va_start(args, format);\
    vfprintf(stderr, format, args);\
    va_end(args);\
    printf("\n"); abort()}
```

But this does not print the arguments correctly.

What is wrong in the macro definition above?

What is the fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler supports ISO style variadic macros, you can define a macro as such:

```
#define error(...) \    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: ");   \
    fprintf(stderr, __VA_ARGS__); \
    fprintf(stderr, "\n"); \
    abort();
```

Alternatively, if you are using GCC, there's also the GNU style variadic macro used as such:

```
#define error(format, args...) \    
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: ");   \
    fprintf(stderr, format , ## args); \
    fprintf(stderr, "\n"); \
    abort();
```

For more information, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html

**Update**

If your compiler does not have variadic macro support, a (poor?) alternative would be to stick to the `va_list` in function approach. If you wish the definition to reside in a header file, then perhaps a static inline function?

```
static inline void error(const char *fmt, ...) {
#define PRINT_ERROR
    va_list args;
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: "); 
    va_start(args, fmt);
    vfprintf(stderr, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    abort();
#endif
}
```

Comment: @shawnchin: Thanks. I tried it in MSVC6.0, MSVS-2005 compilers, it doesnot seem to support variable argument macros. I guess GCC supports, but  do u know of any windows based compiler supporting this?

Comment: @goldenmean: This site says that ISO style Variadic macros was introduced in MSVS-2005 Visual C++ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177415(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: @shawnchin: Are there any peculiar MSVisual Studio project options which one needs to set to enable the compiler to compile this variadic macros. I tried setting few options(e.g. Compile code as C++) Is there any macro to force the compiler to accept these variadic macro extensions(Are they C99 extensions)?

Comment: While i was going through other SO posts, i can across this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139479/how-universally-is-c99-supported/139506#139506/  which says MSVS2005 might not have support for C99 features(Varuiadic macros being one of C99 feature).

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have an MSVS installation to test it out. However, google search results and this SO post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/65037/is-there-a-way-to-write-macros-with-a-variable-argument-list-in-visual-c/65103#65103) claim that variadic macros are indeed supported from VC++ 2005 onwards.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [article with some examples on variable arguments used in a macro](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gcc/cpp_19.html). It looks like it should do what you're looking for. You can use `__VA_ARGS__` in your macro.

Which compiler are you using?

Comment: It looks like it would work all right.  but WHY replace a perfectly good function call with a macro?  It's not like in-lining the code is going to make any difference to performance or anything in this case.  It's just taking some decent code and turning it into crap code

Answer (score 0):

Macros do not (yet?) support variadic arguments and anyway, using `va_list` wouldn't work here, it only works on variadic *function* arguments.

Why do you want to replace the function (which works fine, according to you) with a macro anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Many compilers support GNU style variadic macros, like this:

```
#define error(format,args...) do { \
  fprintf(stderr, "error: " format "\n", ##args); \
  abort(); \
} while(0)
```

However, if you aim for portability, do not use variadic macros.

Comment: @Laalto: Thanks. I tried it in MSVC6.0, MSVS-2005 compilers, it doesnot seem to support variable argument macros. I guess GCC supports, but  do u know of any windows based compiler supporting this?

Comment: I've used this construct on Metrowerks CodeWarrior and various flavors of GCC on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

There's a common extension that does what you want, simply write:

```
#define error(args...) (fputs("Error: ",stdout),printf(args),puts(""))
```

C99 users can also say:

```
#define error(...) (fputs("Error: ",stdout),printf(__VA_ARGS__),puts(""))
```

but there are [some problems](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html) with using `__VA_ARGS__`. Fortunately there's a GCC extension to deal with it, but then you're back to using a compiler-specific extension, and the `args...` mode is more widely available.